# Why my html button sir not working properly?

Tags: html, css, button

I am beginner to HTML and CSS. I have written an HTML text for on/off button. But my buttons are not working properly. I have tried but couldn't find where is the problem.
My html part is:

```css
.s {
  position: relative;
}

.s input {
  display: none;
}

.s1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.s1:before {
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.s input:checked+.s1 {
  background: #00bcd4;
}

.s input:checked+s1:before {
  left: 64px;
}

.s2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.s2:before {
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.s input:checked+.s2 {
  background: #00bcd4;
}

.s input:checked+s2:before {
  left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<label class="s">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="s1"> </span>
    </label>
<label class="s">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="s2"> </span>
    </label>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you create code sandbox link for the same ?

Comment: What result you want to get? You should give more information. What you want to get, what work and not? What do you think "working properly" or not?

Comment: @TrầnHữuHiền If i click my button it is not moving from left to right. I want to move this button left to right when click and vice versa

Comment: working good for me? they toggle colors when clicked

Comment: @johnSmith But i want to toggle in the switch where i click not the another button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a problem with these classes:

```
.s input:checked+s1:before {
  left: 64px;
}

.s input:checked+s2:before {
  left: 64px;
}
```

You should notice it should be:

```
.s input:checked + .s1:before {
  left: 64px;
}

.s input:checked + .s2:before {
  left: 64px;
}
```

Simply, you were missing the `.` of the class selector